# Django - Random sort after distinct

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to do is:

- Always return a random sort for my query
- Query result should not include duplicates
- Support Paging for that

This is my query simplified

```py
# merge two queries and eliminate duplicates
queryset = (items_no_cards | items_no_categories).distinct()

# return a sort order
queryset.order_by('?')
```

If i do this ^ then it returns duplicated items with a random order, if i just do:

```py
# merge two queries and eliminate duplicates
queryset = (items_no_cards | items_no_categories).distinct()

# return a sort order
queryset.order_by("-date_created")
```

No duplicates but returns a sorted order.

I know that i can use a python random function instead of doing *.order_by('?')* but i want to support paging, so it doesn't apply for this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to support paging, then both using the database random, or shuffling at the Django/Python level won't work, since the database will retrieve the data in a random order as well.

Comment: It might be better to use something that looks pseudo-random. For example you can make a view `list/5/2`, where it first sorts on the fifth character, and then on the second. This gives an impression of randomness, and if you alter it to `/7/2` for example it will retrieve data in a totally different order.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds a good option. I will try, thanks @WillemVanOnsem